# Timestamp string to Date

Tags: java, android

How to convert the string to a date

In the string we have a timestamp (for example `"2018-07-11T04:40:30Z"`),
and I want to simply convert this String time to `11-07-2018 16:40:30`

```
String Time =  jresponse.getString("timestamp");
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = sf.parse(Time);
```

I tried many times this code and it doesn't work because I have always this format `"2018-07-11T04:40:30Z"` and not this `11-07-2018 16:40:30` why ?

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: The format don't change I have always this 2018-07-11T04:40:30Z and not this format 11-07-2018 16:40:30

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date may help your issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: I would take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date#answer-20578792) and its Android specific notes at the end. In a nutshell, I think that format would be compatible with the `java.time` package found in most recent Android versions or alternatively with the [ThreeTen-Backport for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). Either one also provides useful methods for date, time and datetime handling, so they are not only useful for parsing.

Comment: Consider dropping both `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` since both are long outdated. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), is so much nicer to work with. `Instant.parse("2018-07-11T04:40:30Z"` gives you an `Instant` (the replacement for `Date`) even without an explicit formatter.

Comment: I have added a second original question in the “This question already has an answer here” box. I think it may be more helpful than the first. I particularly recommend my own answer there, of course. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse dates like `"2018-07-11T04:40:30Z"`then you should change the format as `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"` will never work with that date. The correct format should be something like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`.

Comment: I think the T needs to be quoted, or escaped? yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ

Comment: Yes, I'll update my answer. Thank you.